# Argument of type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following function that shows the following error in the  - Can anyone suggest why I am getting this error?

```
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  questionnaire: FormGroup;
  items;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private postDataIntoDB: ServerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.questionnaire = this.formBuilder.group({
  items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
});}

  createItem(): FormGroup {
      return this.formBuilder.group({
      sno: ['',Validators.required],
      question:['',Validators.required],
      option1: ['',Validators.required],
      option2: ['',Validators.required],
      option3: ['',Validators.required],
      option4: ['',Validators.required],
      option5: ['',Validators.required]
});}

  addItem(): void {
     this.items = this.questionnaire.get('items') as FormArray;
     this.items.push(this.createItem());
}}
```

I am getting error on `this.postDataIntoDB.storeData(this.questionnaire)`:

> Argument of type'FormGroup' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string'

```
onSubmit() {
    this.postDataIntoDB.storeData(this.questionnaire)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
          (error)=> console.log(error)
     )}
```

Comment: `storeData` is probably expecting a `string` as parameter, you are giving a `FormGroup` instead. May be you will have to do `JSON.stringify(this.questionnaire.value)`. Can you add `storeData` function body?

Comment: share definition of storeData method

Comment: Thanks my dear friend here works fine